# What is the difference between getPastEvents() vs events.MyEvent({ fromBlock: 0})?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, events

What is the difference between using `myContract.getPastEvents()` to get past events and `using myContract.events.MyEvent({ fromBlock: 0, })` ?

Also, if I pass to `fromBlock` a block number that has not been mined yet, does it work as expected?

Comment: Maybe `MyEvent` does not handle old events.

Comment: Answered in stack overflow, I copied the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, both will return the events fired in the past. But `MyEvent` can additionally subscribe to an event. So it could be fired for every event emitted in the future.

However, [`MyEvent`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) will return the events **one-by-one**. And for every event fired in the past and/or in the future, the **callback** will be called.

And, [`getPastEvents`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents) will return the events **all-in-one-shot**. It will return an **array** of the events fired in the past.

---

Note: do not use `{ fromBlock: 0, }` for `options` on the **main-net**. You will wait for a very long time and the script will most likely terminate before any value is returned. To be able to get a result specify a resonable number of blocks between `fromBlock` and `toBlock`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `MyEvent` lets you specify filters within a specific event type (you can filter by parameter values), whereas `getPastEvents` returns all events for an event type.

The syntax you posted is nearly identical. The main difference is `getPastEvents` will return all events that have occurred up until the block number the node you’re connected to is synced to. `MyEvent` will return those same events, plus will call the callback on any new events that occur as new blocks are added to the chain.

---

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51664434/4428008